# Проблема с передачей элемента массива в сессию wordpress

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, сервер, циклы

Всем привет.
Пишу php функцию на вордпресс.

Суть в том, что пользователь выбирает в выпадающем списке свой город. Выбранный город записывается в глобальную переменную вордпресса в сессию для того, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы отобразить посты, метка которого соответствует выбранному городу.

После выбора  пункта должна просто обновиться страница и вместо "Выбор города" должно появиться имя выбранного города. На его основе я буду отображать посты только с меткой этого города вот таким способом:

```
<?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>    
<?php if(have_posts()) : query_posts('category_name=news&numberposts=0&paged='.$page.'&tag='.get_query_var($vibor_gor[0])); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    ...
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Для наглядности посмотрите картинку ниже.

[image: Выпадающий список]

Функция должна отслеживать изменение поля `select` и записывать его значение в глобальную переменную в сессию.

Саму функцию пишу в файле темы function.php

Вот код:

```
function select_city() {
    session_start(); //открываю сессию (может быть открываю не там)
global $vibor_gor; //объявляю глобаньную переменную
    $vibor_gor = array(); //говорю что эта переменная массив

    $tags = get_tags(); //получаю массив существующих тегов
foreach ($tags as $tag){
    array_push($vibor_gor, $tag->name); //циклом вытягиваю имена тегов
}
    if(!empty($_SESSION['sesgor'])) //если в нем что-то есть
    {
        $vstavka = $_SESSION['sesgor'];
    }
    else $vstavka= "Выбор города"; //если пользователь еще не выбрал город, то выводим это
$html = '<select class="vibor_gor" name="vibor_gor" onchange="location.reload()">
         <option disabled selected value>'.$vstavka.'</option>'; //первая опция просто для вида, что тут можно выбарть город
foreach ($vibor_gor as $value){
    $html .= "<option value='{$value}'>{$value}</option>"; //заполняем все опции нашими тегами городов
    array_push($_SESSION['sesgor'], $value); //тут я пытаюсь заполнить массив в сессии нашими городами
}   
$html .= '</select>';
echo $html;
};
```

Проблема в том, что после выбора города и обновления страницы значение `select` либо остается "Выбор города", либо "Array", либо последним в списке массива, а именно "Старый Оскол", либо вообще пустым. Пробовал по разному, но всегда не то что нужно.

Пробовал искать плагин для выбора городов. То что нужно - нет, или не нашел. Если хотите - используйте этот код для написания такового плагина на вордпресс. Очень будет востребован.

Comment: Когда я вижу `query_posts` у меня сразу срабатывает `break` на вопрос. Гугли почему его нельзя использовать и как делать правильно - возможно заодно и решишь задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу несколько проблем.

1. [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php) лучше использовать в самом начале скрипта, т.к. не понятно когда запустится ваша функция, сколько раз она запустится, и запустится ли вообще. А сессия - это глобальный массив, и по-хорошему должен быть доступен везде и всегда.
2. Вы хотите запомнить в сессии выбор пользователя, но сохраняете значение на этапе формирования формы, а не при её сабмите. В скрипте, который вы здесь представили, вы просто заполняете в сессию все города, которые у вас есть, отсюда и `ARRAY` в качестве вабранного элемента (т.е. в сесии действительно хранится массив).

В итоге, вам нужно сохранять сессию, когда вы уже получили что-то от юзера. Т.е. где-то внутри `if (have_posts())` нужно вытащить значение, которое выбрал пользователь и сохранить его в сессию. Не знаю как точно работает WordPress, но подозреваю, что как-то так:

```
$_SESSION['sesgor'] = get_query_var($vibor_gor[0]));
```

3. Ну и в целом код довольно кривенький, прислушайтесь к совету @SeVlad в комментарии к вопросу.